# Formulario com $_files não salva o arquivo nas pastas do site

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Olá meu projeito tem um form onde pode ser enviada uma imagem, ele salva os  dados do form no BD porém não insere a imagem nos arquivos. alguém pode dizer onde está meu erro?

```
<?php session_start();
include_once("../conexao.php");

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$desc_vid = $_POST["desc_vid"];
$tempo = $_POST["tempo"];
$star_1 = $_POST["star_1"];
$star_2 = $_POST["star_2"];
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$tags = $_POST["tags"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$categoria_id = $_POST["categoria_id"];
$categoria_id2 = $_POST["categoria_id2"];
$categoria_id3 = $_POST["categoria_id3"];
$categoria_id4 = $_POST["categoria_id4"];
$categoria_id5 = $_POST["categoria_id5"];

// Local onde imagem vai ser salva
$_UP['pasta'] = '../../videos/thumb/';
// Tamanho da imagem
$_UP['tamanho'] = 1024*1024*100; //5Mb
// Exrensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');
// Renomear a imagem
$_UP['renomear'] = false;

// Tipos de erro de UpLoad do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'Imagem maior que o limite do php';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'Imagem muito grande';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'UpLoad da imagem feita parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Erro no UpLoad da imagem';

// Verifica se houve algum erro
if($_FILES['imagem']['erros'] != 0){
    die("Não foi possivel fazer UpLoad, Erro: <br />". $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['imagem']['erros']]);
exit;
}

// Verifica qual a extensão
$img_nome = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
$img_separador = explode('.', $img_nome);
$extensao = strtolower(end($img_separador));
//$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['imagem']['name'])));
if(array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes'])=== false){
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Arquivo não compatível: png, jpg, jpeg e gif. \");
</script>
";
}
// Verifica o tamanho
else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['imagem']['size']){
    echo "Imagem muito grande, limite de 5Mb";
}
// Salva nos arquivos do site
else{
    //Verifica se deve trocar o nome da imagem
    if($_UP['renomear'] == true){
        // Cria nome Baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão
        $nome_final = time().'.jpg';
}else{
    // Mantem o nome da imagem
    $nome_final = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];
}
// Verifica se é possivel mover a imagem para a pasta escolhida
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'].$nome_final)){
    // Upload efetuado com sucesso
    $nome = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome);
    $desc_vid = $conectar->real_escape_string($desc_vid);
    $tempo = $conectar->real_escape_string($tempo);
    $star_1 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_1);
    $star_2 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_2);
    $nome_final = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome_final);
    $tags = $conectar->real_escape_string($tags);
    $description = $conectar->real_escape_string($description);
    $categoria_id = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id);
    $categoria_id2 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id2);
    $categoria_id3 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id3);
    $categoria_id4 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id4);
    $categoria_id5 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id5);

    $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO videos (nome, desc_vid, tempo, star_1, star_2, imagem, tags, description, categoria_id, categoria_id2, categoria_id3, categoria_id4, categoria_id5, created) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$desc_vid."', '".$tempo."', '".$star_1."', '".$star_2."', '".$nome_final."', '".$tags."', '".$description."', '".$categoria_id."', '".$categoria_id2."', '".$categoria_id3."', '".$categoria_id4."', '".$categoria_id5."', NOW())") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL= http://houseofcoin.com/xxx/administrativo.php?link=9'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Cadastrado com Sucesso.\");
</script>
";
}else{
    // Falha no UpLoad
    $nome = $conectar->real_escape_string($nome);
    $desc_vid = $conectar->real_escape_string($desc_vid);
    $tempo = $conectar->real_escape_string($tempo);
    $star_1 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_1);
    $star_2 = $conectar->real_escape_string($star_2);
    $tags = $conectar->real_escape_string($tags);
    $description = $conectar->real_escape_string($description);
    $categoria_id = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id);
    $categoria_id2 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id2);
    $categoria_id3 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id3);
    $categoria_id4 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id4);
    $categoria_id5 = $conectar->real_escape_string($categoria_id5);

    $query = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO videos (nome, desc_vid, tempo, star_1, star_2, tags, description, categoria_id, categoria_id2, categoria_id3, categoria_id4, categoria_id5, created) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$desc_vid."', '".$tempo."', '".$star_1."', '".$star_2."',  '".$tags."', '".$description."', '".$categoria_id."', '".$categoria_id2."', '".$categoria_id3."', '".$categoria_id4."', '".$categoria_id5."', NOW())") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL= http://houseofcoin.com/xxx/administrativo.php?link=9'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Cadastrado não Realizado.\");
</script>
";
}
}

/*$query = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO videos (nome, desc_vid, tempo, star_1, star_2, imagem, categoria_id, tags, description, created) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$desc_vid."', '".$tempo."', '".$star_1."', '".$star_2."', '".$nome_final."', '".$categoria_id."', '".$tags."', '".$description."', NOW())");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>
<?php
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conectar) != 0){
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL= http://houseofcoin.com/xxx/administrativo.php?link=9'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Cadastrado com Sucesso.\");
</script>
";
}else {
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL= http://houseofcoin.com/xxx/administrativo.php?link=9'>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"Cadastrado não Realizado.\");
</script>
";
}*/
?>
```

Código do form

```
<div class="container" style="width: 100%">

<div class="page-header"><h1>Cadastrar</h1></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="processa/proc_cad_vid.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="nome" placeholder="Título do Vídeo">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descrição</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="desc_vid" placeholder="Descrição do Vídeo"></textarea>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tempo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="tempo" placeholder="Tempo de Vídeo">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Star 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="star_1" placeholder="Star 1">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Star 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="star_2" placeholder="Star 2">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" name="imagem" id="exampleInputFile">
        </div>  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tags</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="texto" class="form-control" name="tags" placeholder="Tags">
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Descrição que o Google Recebe"></textarea>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria 1</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id">
                <option>Selecione</option>
                <?php 
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    $dados = str_replace(" ","",$dados);
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>"><?php echo $dados['nome'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria 2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id2">
                <option>Selecione</option>
                <?php 
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    $dados = str_replace(" ","",$dados);
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>"><?php echo $dados['nome'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria 3</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id3">
                <option>Selecione</option>
                <?php 
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    $dados = str_replace(" ","",$dados);
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>"><?php echo $dados['nome'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria 4</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id4">
                <option>Selecione</option>
                <?php 
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    $dados = str_replace(" ","",$dados);
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>"><?php echo $dados['nome'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categoria 5</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="categoria_id5">
                <option>Selecione</option>
                <?php 
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM categorias");
                while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                    $dados = str_replace(" ","",$dados);
                ?>  
                <option value="<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>"><?php echo $dados['nome'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div><br>
</div></div>
```

já tentei colocar o $querry camada e forçar o erro, mas ele não insere nenhum dado. Desde já Obrigado.

Comment: De onde vem essa variavel `$_UP`? Tenho certeza que ela não é uma superglobal. Poste também o HTML do formulário.

Comment: perdão achei que não seria importante, editando agora...

Comment: Não sei bem dizer o que ocorre, mas pode tentar depurar a resposta do mysql assim `$query = mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO videos ...") or die(mysqli_error($conectar));`

Comment: ele apresentou esse erro "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's"

Comment: Talvez esteja faltando escapar algo dessas variáveis.

Comment: escapar? enviar?, Acabei de fazer um teste, se eu digitar só texto ele registra normal, mas se eu uso "-" "[" "0" ele apresenta esse erro, mas todos os campos do BD estão em varchar e o tempo regista "00:00" sem problemas, alguma ideia?

Comment: Faça como o Guilherme respondeu.

Answer (score 1):

O erro deve estar ocorrendo devido a alguma frase com apostrofo `'`, isto conflita com os apostrofos do mysql, porque ele pensa que fechou uma coluna, mas em seguida vem um caractere inexperado.

Pra corrigir pode usar `mysqli_real_escape_string` ou [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Antes de executar a query com `mysqli_real_escape_string`, faça isto:

```
$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($nome);
$desc_vid = mysqli_real_escape_string($desc_vid);
$tempo = mysqli_real_escape_string($tempo);
$star_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($star_1);
$star_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($star_2);
$nome_final = mysqli_real_escape_string($nome_final);
$categoria_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($categoria_id);
$tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($tags);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($description);
```

Com prepared statements deve ser algo como:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conectar, "INSERT INTO videos (nome, desc_vid, tempo, star_1, star_2, imagem, categoria_id, tags, description, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $nome);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $desc_vid);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tempo);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $star_1);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $star_2);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $nome_final);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $categoria_id);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tags);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $description);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Mais detalhes em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Apesar da minha ignorância relacionada a php, Consegui !

Comment: @ÉoRonaldoDll removeu o aceito da resposta por algum motivo em especial?

Comment: não resolveu o problema, com a sua resposta melhorou, pois agora ele salva as informações no BD, mas ainda não salva a imagem

Comment: @ÉoRonaldoDll ocorre alguma mensagem de erro após o upload?

Comment: não, quando seleciono a imagem, ele aparece do rodapé carregando as %, então tento cadastrar, retorna a msg que foi cadastrado... salva todas as informações no BD, porém não salva a imagem nos arquivos